# Entity Framework 7 error version

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, relationship

I have two class the first is "Movimentacao":

```
public class Movimentacao
    {
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public decimal Valor { get; set; }

    public DateTime Data { get; set; }

    public int UsuarioId { get; set; }

    public Usuario Usuario { get; set; }
}
```

and the other one "Usuario":

```
  public class Usuario
    {
    public int Id { get; set; }


    public string Nome { get; set; }


    public string Email { get; set; }

}
```

Give the error: "Reference of object is not defined for an instance of object"

Class index.cshtml:

```
@foreach (var m in Model)
        {
            <tr>

                <td>@m.Id</td>
                <td>@m.Usuario.Id></td> //Error line
                <td>@m.Valor</td>

            </tr>
        }
```

In class context of version 6 is use"DbModelBuilder" but not exist at version 7, i would like to known what can i do , what i can use in place of HasRequired():

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
    modelBuilder.Entity<Movimentacao>()
    .HasRequired(c => c.UsuarioId);


    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

}
```

Class Controller:

```
public class MovimentacaoController : Controller
    {
        private MovimentacaoDAO movimentacaoDAO;
        private UsuarioDAO usuarioDAO;

        public MovimentacaoController(MovimentacaoDAO movimentacaoDAO, UsuarioDAO usuarioDAO)
        {
            this.movimentacaoDAO = movimentacaoDAO;
            this.usuarioDAO = usuarioDAO;
        }

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(movimentacaoDAO.Lista());
        }

        public ActionResult Form()
        {
            ViewBag.Usuarios = usuarioDAO.Lista();
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Adiciona(Movimentacao movimentacao)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                movimentacaoDAO.Adiciona(movimentacao);
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.Usuarios = usuarioDAO.Lista();
                return View("Form");
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no EF7.  Here's the relevant EF Core documentation example:

```
class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>()
            .Property(b => b.Url)
            .IsRequired();
    }
}

public class Blog
{
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/required-optional